# Visual Studio Code always converting to Spaces

Tags: macos, indentation, autoindent, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get my VS code to always indent with tabs.

I use a `.eslintrc.json` file with the rule `indent: ["warn", "tab"]`, this works for some files. I also have a `.editorconfig` file with `indent_style = tabs`. In my user settings, I have `"editor.insertSpaces": false` and `"editor.tabSize": 4`.

However, in `.js` files (and so far, only `.js` files), whenever I hit save, VS Code auto-converts my tabs to four spaces and messed up my linter.

This happens even if I set the `.js` file to indent with tabs on a per-file level. Does anyone know if this is a hidden setting, or is it perhaps a bug that I should report?

On OSX Sierra 10.12.1, VS Code 1.8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this same issue and tracked it down to the "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" extension. After disabling this extension, it fixed the issue for me. I would try disabling any extensions you have that do auto-formatting of javascript files.